# How to develop an Opera Mobile plugin?

Tags: plugins, mobile, opera

I'm totally new to opera mobile addons. Can someone suggest me a site which can help me to get started?

I'm currently using a Sony Ericsson P990i. It is loaded with Opera Mobile 8.65.

I type "opera:plugins" in the Opera Mobile address bar; it showed me the list of plugins installed.

So, I'd like to develop plugins for my personal use.

Is there any tutorial/examples of Hello World for opera mobile plugin development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Till recently we in Opera did not have the ability for running extensions in Opera Mobile. We have recently released a labs build with support for extensions http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/extensions-opera-mobile-labs/

The way to create Opera extensions is documented here http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/getting-started-with-opera-extensions/ The idea is to create extensions, and not exactly worry about desktop or mobile. Just creating nice extensions regardless of platform.